# How much time has passed between Crake's outbreak and start of book in in "Oryx and Crake"

Tags: oryx-and-crake

Just finished *Oryx and Crake*, but it isn't clear to me how much time passed between the spread of the pandemic by Crake's BlyssPluss pill until the start of the book when Snowman is living adjacent to the crakers. Is it supposed to be months or years?

Comment: Some of the history leading up to the outbreak are some of the subject matter of *The Year of the Flood* and *MaddAddam**.